# Why is "didn't quite appreciate" right and "didn't so appreciate" wrong?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adverbs

> Probably they didn’t ____ appreciate the risks involved in entering
>   the competitive world of automobile manufacture.

This question was asked in an exam. For the answer, we were given the following five options:

> A. too 
> B. quite 
> C. more 
> D. so 
> E. as

The answer was B) *quite*. Why can't *so* be used here?

Comment: "didn't so appreciate" is not idiomatic.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Have a look at he [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good questions.

Answer (score 0):

'quite' and 'so' have similar meanings when used as an adverb. However 'so' can also be used as a conjunction. For this reason using 'so' makes the sentence sound confusing, where 'quite' is a better adverb to use, as its grammatical purpose is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

These adverbs have specific uses.

Quite can be used to mean 'to the greatest possible degree' which is exactly the meaning here,

> "they didn't appreciate the risks to the greatest possible degree..."

So has a similar use but not identical, it can be used to mean 'to such a great degree'.

> "they didn't appreciate the risks to such a great degree..."

But to such a great degree, compared to what? You would use this for example if you were saying "don't look so angry" - meaning don't look angry to such a great degree (as you are looking presently) for instance. So there is a vehicle of comparison, when you use 'so' like this.

In the case of your question however, they did not understand the risks to the greatest degree (or fullest extent if you like) - which is why 'quite' is the correct choice of adverb here.

You can read more about the specific uses of these two adverbs [here (quite)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quite) and [here (so)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/so_2)